# How can I trigger click event onload page

Tags: jquery

I am having anchor tag in my page and popup blockers is enabled in my browser but when I perform manually click the link its working fine and open the link in new tab window but when I want trigger click event on-load page, then it's not working and show the message popup blocked.

Comment: That is the popup blocker working exactly as intended. If it was possible for you to weasel your way around it this way, it would be useless. Duh.

Comment: But, when i click the link then why it's not show me the popup blocked message

Comment: Because YOU clicked it, not a script

Comment: @mplungjan Okay thanks

Comment: The main criterion for whether to allow or block a popup, is whether it was “caused”/triggered by user interaction (a click in most cases), or the site author tried to open it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I perform manually click the link its working fine and open the link in new tab window but when I want trigger click event on-load page, then it's not working and show the message popup blocked

That is the popup blocker working exactly as intended. If it was possible for you to circumvent it this way, it would be useless.

The main criterion for whether to allow or block a popup, is whether it was “caused”/triggered by user interaction (a click in most cases), or the site author tried to open it automatically.